# InvalidArgumentException HELP Database [] not configured Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Ijust cloned a laravel project from bitbucket and i'm using nginx server for my local devs.
But when i navigate to the url for my project(locally) i get this error.

Please help!

Comment: Did you configure your database and .env file? I mean did you create a database on that machine where you cloned the project. And declared the database name, database user and password in .env file for that project and run migrations?

Comment: I did not run migrations. but created the database and imported the .sql file.
Again the project did not come with a .env file

Comment: Which db are you using? MySQL or some other? And which OS?

Comment: did you create the .env file before user EddyTheDove made his answer?

Answer (score 1):

Create an `.env` file at the root. The content should be something like this

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mysql

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Replace all the database values above. Then run `php artisan key:generate` to generate your app key.

Comment: The OP already created the .env file and imported the .sql file, please read the comments before answering the question.

Comment: The OP has not stated anywhere they created the file, but rather "Again the project did not come with a .env file". Read again before teaching people how to read.